# backspace not working in vim inside cmd or ConEmu or console2, cygwin terminals on windows 7

Tags: vim, cygwin, conemu, console2

hitting single backspace character taking time to delete a single character in Insert Mode. If I type 2 backspace character quickly then the text in that line become highlighted and even `:set hlsearch!` is not removing the highlighted text.

I have tried `:set backspace=2` but still the same problem.

Any other workaround for this issue?

Comment: You probably have macros starting with backspace.  Read `:help timeout` for more information.

Comment: I haven't set any macro for timeout, but at the same time I am not sure if any plugin is doing so. If that is the case this behaviour should also be coming with gvim, but this is not the case, inside gvim backspace is working fine.

Comment: You have no idea what your plugins can do behind your back. :) If the slowdown happens only in insert mode, run `:imap` and look for mappings that refer to `<BS>`.

Comment: I add the same kind of problem with cygwin, backspace maked a space in the terminal but the content was deleted. Try to reinstall the `terminfo` package.

Comment: If your problem persists while running `Vim` in `mintty.exe` the problem does not relate to ConEmu or Console2.

Comment: Yes... sure it is not related with any particular terminal, I guess it may be due to any vim setting or anything which is common in all these terminals.